# Class 'JObject' not found

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hello everybody trying to solve my problem!

2 days ago I tried to install an extension (simpleslideshow). After the installation was not successful and I got an error about the privileges and then site went blank. I cannot even access the admin page. Now I tried to delete the extension folder via FTP and the site still doesn't work. I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JObject' not found in *domainpath* /public_html/libraries/joomla/application/base.php on line 23
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension should not be enabled if the install didn't complete, but just to be sure look at the end of the #__extensions table and disable / delete the newly added lines.

Then delete all files (administrator, component, modules, plugins) that were packed with the extension.

Finally, apply a clean Joomla update package to your site, just to make sure your installation didn't compromise the core

Clear the cache, tmp and you should be back to where you were.

Next time, make backups before doing anything to reduce the risk and the hassle.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem!
yes, it was all my fault because i thought that its gonna be a 5min work:).